# Commiting large amount of files with git

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am brand new to github and am trying to upload a .zip to my github repository. This ZIP contains of about 950 files but is no more than 10mb in size. Each file is pretty small and belongs to a C# project. I am trying to upload all 950 files to github (not upload, but commiting). I see that I have had 900 changes in the changes tab and I go ahead and type a summary and hit commit.

The commit button just goes round in circles forever, I have literally left my PC on for over 6 hours at a point and it is still going round. I don't know if I am meant to do anything else but at the moment all I am doing is dragging the files into the rep folder in C:\Users\Username\Documents\Github\MyRep and then hitting commit in the github for desktop window.

It just commits so slow, it works if you upload about 50 files at a time but it breaks after doing about 2 commits, it just is acting very slow and strange, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When you say upload, you mean push?

Comment: From your question and your comments below, I didn't understand if you first extract the files from your zip and try to commit them or you try to commit the zip itself. Did you succeed commit other small things?

Comment: Commit is a local operation (not related to the network) thus it shouldnt take that long..